# php downloading a file from ftp doesn't work locally using XAMPP works only with older files on ftp

Tags: php

When I run the code below the local file gets deleted, I cannot work out why:

```
$local_file = 'test.csv';
$server_file = 'test_directory/test2.csv';
$ftp_server="servername";
$ftp_user="test";
$ftp_pass="pass";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password`
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass);

ftp_pasv($conn_id, TRUE);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

So I get an error on the console showing cannot open no file or directory.

Edit:

Renaming the file to something else other than I am getting from ftp does not delete the file but still doesn't work.

I am running this in XAMMP htdocs location.

Edit:

Problem is if I add a new file to the ftp server, it works with existing ones even though the permission is the same.

Comment: Are you sure that local file gets deleted? Maybe it's just what it says - you don't have permission to create that file.

Comment: @mlask It does delete, I create it with touch file.csv and it is there I can open it and everything. I run the php script and it deletes :(

Comment: @mlask okay it doesn't delete if I rename it something else other than the file I am downloading from ftp

Comment: can you check if the wrong variables (`$ftp_username` and `$ft_password`  instead of `$ftp_user` and `$ftp_pass`) is in your code or just a mistake from copying it into the question?

Comment: @Cashbee will change that was a mistake from copying it into the question thanks

Comment: Try using an absolute path for both files. Also make sure the file exists on the server, it might just delete the file because the server file doesn't exist.

Comment: @PascalClaes I've tried this and I get the same problem also I added the file on the server so it definitely exists

Comment: @PascalClaes I've noticed if I add new files to the ftp it doesn't work but with existing files on their it works, any ideas?

Comment: File permissions?

Comment: @PascalClaes its not permissions all have 777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is a corrupt file on the ftp server. I tried with a different file and it works.